# Strong convexity and strong monotonicity of the sub-differential

Tags: convex-analysis

I know how to show that when $f$ is proper and $\mu$-strongly convex, its subgradient $\partial f$ is $\mu$-strongly monotone. Is the converse true?

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and $f : H \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb R}$ proper. I claim that the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is $\mu$-strongly convex, that is
   $$
   f[(1-t)x+ty] \leq (1-t)f(x) + tf(y) - \frac{t(1-t)}{2}\mu |x-y|^2
   $$
2. $ f(y) \geq f(x) + (x^* , y-x) + \frac{\mu}{2} |x-y|^2,\quad \forall x,y \in H,\quad \forall x^* \in \partial  f(x)$
3. $\partial f$ is $\mu$-strongly monotone, that is
   $$
   (x^*-y^* , x-y) \geq \mu |x-y|^2,\quad \forall x,y \in H,\quad \forall x^* \in \partial f(x),\quad \forall y^* \in \partial f(y).
   $$

Proof of $1 \Longrightarrow 2$ :
Suppose that $f$ is $\mu$ strongly convex, let $x,y \in H$, $x^* \in \partial f(x)$ and $0 < t < 1$. Apply the inequality to $x + t(y-x)$ in place of $y$:
$$
f(x) + (x^* , t(y-x)) \leq f(x + t(y-x)) \leq (1-t)f(x) + tf(y) - \frac{t(1-t)}{2}\mu |x-y|^2.
$$
Simplifying by $f(x)$, dividing by $t>0$ and letting $t$ going to $0$ we get 2.$\square$

Proof of $2 \Longrightarrow 3$ :
Suppose that $f$ satisfy the estimate 2, let $x,y \in H$, $x^* \in \partial f(x)$ and $y^* \in \partial f(y)$. We have
$$
f(y) \geq f(x) + (x^* , y-x) + \frac{\mu}{2}|x-y|^2,\quad f(x) \geq f(y) + (y^* , x-y) + \frac{\mu}{2}|x-y|^2
$$
so summing up we get $\partial f$ to be $\mu$ strongly monotone.$\square$

Now I experience some troubles to show that 3 implies 1 even in the $C^1$ case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not true in general, the subdifferential might be empty if you don't at least assume it's convex.

Comment: Then how about the convex and $C^1$ case?

Comment: By definition of subdifferential $u\in\partial f(x)$,

$$f(x) \geq f(y) + \langle u, x-y\rangle$$

Now add and subtract a subgradient of $f$ at $y$ in the inner product and use the strong monotonicity:
$$f(x)\geq f(y) + \langle u, x-y\rangle\\
=f(y) + \langle u-v+v, x-y\rangle\\ 
=f(y) + \langle u-v, x-y\rangle + \langle v, x-y\rangle\\ 
\geq f(y) + \mu\|x-y\|^2 + \langle v, x-y\rangle
$$

Which gives

$$f(y)\leq f(x) + \langle v,x-y\rangle +\mu\|x-y\|^2$$

i.e., 3 implies 2

Comment: Adapting this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996183/equivalent-definitions-of-convexity-for-f-in-mathcal-c1-mathbb-rn to the strongly monotone $C^1$ case is very straightforward, you just need to use strong monotonicity instead of monotonicity when looking at $g'(t_2)-g'(t_1)$.

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki in your second comment, the first inequality is wrong. You should have taken $u \in \partial f(y)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to the original question is negative, even for $f\in \Gamma_0(\mathbb R)$. To see it consider the following facts. There $f \in \Gamma_0(H)$.

1. If $f$ is $\mu$ strongly convex, then $\partial f$ is $\mu$ strongly monotone.
2. $\partial f$ is $\mu$ strongly monotone if and only if $\partial f^*$ is $\mu$ co coersive.
3. If $f$ is $C^1(H;\mathbb R)$ and $\nabla f$ is $L$ Lipschitz, then $\partial f$ is $\frac 1 L$ co coersive (this is the Baillon Haddad theorem).
4. $f$ is $\mu$ strongly convex if and only if $f^*$ is $C^1(H ; \mathbb R)$ and $\nabla f^*$ is $\frac 1 \mu$ Lipschitz.

Then consider $f \in \Gamma_0(\mathbb R)$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{ccc}
x^2 & \text{if} & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
+ \infty & \text{else}
\end{array} \right.
$$
We can compute its subgradient
$$
\partial f(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{ccc}
\{2x\} & \text{if} & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
\emptyset & \text{else}
\end{array} \right.
$$
which is cocoersive
$$
(2x-2y,x-y) = 2|x-y|^2 \geq \frac1 2|2x-2y|^2.
$$
However $f$ is not $C^1$, so the reciprocal of Baillon Haddad is false. Moreover this is a counter example to the original question because if the original question had a positive answer, $g := f^*$ would have a strongly monotone subgradient hence be strictly convex and its conjugate $g^* = f^{**}=f$ would be $C^1$.

Comment: This counterexample is incorrect. The subdifferential of f at 1 is 2x plus the normal cone to the constraint, that is R+. By taking x=0, x*=0, y=1 and y*=1+t for positive t, the cocoercivity inequality becomes impossible because the lower term grows faster with t than the upper bound. Overall, it is a general fact that cocoercive operators are single-valued and Lipschitz continuous, which is not true here.